# request_kerberos doesn't work

Tags: python, django, kerberos

Are you able to tell me why I cannot use the request_kerberos module ? this is my code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound ,HttpResponseRedirect
import requests
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth, OPTIONAL
```

I have already installed this module ,but when I'm opening the webpage I see that:

```
No module named winkerberos
```

I've checked the code and the problem is here ,kerberos.py file, first 4 lines:

```
try:
    import kerberos
except ImportError:
    import winkerberos as kerberos
```

winkerberos is for Windows OS and I'm using the CentOS

So, why my system cannot import that module ?